# getSessionToken() not working in Parse

Tags: parse-platform

Below is my parse cloud code. I am unable to get user session even when I am using master key. Is it not possible to get User session even if we use mater key to retrieve user?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getFSUserSession", getFSUserSession);

function getFSUserSession(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  //Removed some codes here to make it short
  var someID = request.params.user;
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo('familySearchID', someID);
  query.ascending('createdAt');
  query.first({useMasterKey: true}).then(function (user) {
      console.log(typeof user.getSessionToken());//this returns function 
      console.log(user.getSessionToken()); //this logs No Message provided
      response.success(user.getSessionToken());
  })  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to disable Require Revocable Sessions to make this work. After disabling Require Revocable Sessions in settings we can make an api request to /1/upgradeToRevocableSession to get the upgraded session token.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getFSUserSession", getFSUserSession);

function getFSUserSession(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  //Removed some codes here to make it short
  var someID = request.params.user;
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo('familySearchID', someID);
  query.ascending('createdAt');
  query.first({useMasterKey: true}).then(function (user) {
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/upgradeToRevocableSession',
     headers: {
      'X-Parse-Application-Id': Parse.applicationId,
      'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': restKey,
      'X-Parse-Session-Token': user.getSessionToken()
     }
    });
  }).then(function (httpResponse) {
    var sessionObject = httpResponse.data;
    if (sessionObject.sessionToken) {
      return Parse.Promise.as(sessionObject.sessionToken);
    }
    return Parse.Promise.error('Unable to get Session token');
  });  
}
```

Comment: I hit the same wall on the cloud code. Even though the application is created in the last month, the session token was null unless i disabled the "Require Revocable Sessions". Any ideea what's wrong ? Of course i use the master key.

Comment: May be this post will explain it a bit more. http://blog.parse.com/announcements/announcing-new-enhanced-sessions/

Comment: @Yalamber I have implemented Google login with cloud code years ago. Now I have added Parse.User.enableRevocableSession() line to cloud code and getting session start with r: but this is only for a  new user (First time) registration. But when I am trying to log in, I am getting "Invalid session token" from parse- server hosted on heroku.

Comment: @Yalamber Do you have any suggestions? We're on a really tight deadline and we can't seem to find a solution anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: No idea man. It's been a long time since I have looked in to parse now.